# vb.net cant connect to mysql

Tags: mysql, vb.net

i tried to create on login system with mysql. but i dont know it doesnt work. It give my try again every time whats the problem?

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    mysqlconn = New MySqlConnection
    mysqlconn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=;database=tes"
    Dim reader As MySqlDataReader

    Try
        mysqlconn.Open()
        Dim query As String = "select * from kullanicilar where 'username=" & TextBox1.Text & "' and 'password=" & TextBox2.Text & "'"
        komut = New MySqlCommand(query, mysqlconn)
        reader = komut.ExecuteReader
        Dim girdimi As Integer = 0

        If reader.Read Then
            girdimi = girdimi + 1
        End If

        If girdimi = 1 Then
            Form2.Show()
        ElseIf girdimi = 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("try again")
        End If
        mysqlconn.Close()
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        mysqlconn.Dispose()

    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: select * from kullanicilar where 'username=foo' and 'password=bar' should be select * from kullanicilar where username='foo' and password='bar'

Comment: MessageBox.Show(query)

Comment: Oh thanks, it works

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way (based on DataReader [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2)):

```
   Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    mysqlconn = New MySqlConnection
    mysqlconn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=;database=tes"
    Dim reader As MySqlDataReader

    Try
        mysqlconn.Open()
        Dim query As String = "select * from kullanicilar where username='" & TextBox1.Text & "' and password='" & TextBox2.Text & "'"
        komut = New MySqlCommand(query, mysqlconn)
        reader = komut.ExecuteReader()
        Dim girdimi As Integer = 0

        If reader.HasRows Then
            Do While reader.Read()
                girdimi = girdimi + 1
                If girdimi = 1 Then
                    Form2.Show()
                ElseIf girdimi = 0 Then
                    MessageBox.Show("try again")
               End If
        Loop
        End If

        mysqlconn.Close()
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        mysqlconn.Dispose()

    End Try
End Sub
```